# Why using Area under curve in manim is giving me an error?

Tags: python-3.x, manim

I am trying to show area under a curve using manim
this is my code

```
from manimlib import *
import numpy as np

class GraphExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
      ax = Axes((-3, 10), (-1, 8))
      ax.add_coordinate_labels()


      curve = ax.get_graph(lambda x: 2 * np.sin(x))

      self.add(ax,curve)

      area = ax.get_area_under_graph(graph=curve, x_range= (0,2))

      self.add(curve, area)
      self.wait(1)
```

this is giving an error message

```
File "c:\manim-master\manimlib\__main__.py", line 17, in main scene.run()
File "c:\manim-master\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 75, in run self.construct()
File "test.py", line 21, in construct self.add(area)
File "c:\manim-master\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 209, in add self.remove(*new_mobjects)
File "c:\manim-master\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 226, in remove self.mobjects = restructure_list_to_exclude_certain_family_members(
File "c:\manim-master\manimlib\utils\family_ops.py", line 25, in restructure_list_to_exclude_certain_family_members 
to_remove = extract_mobject_family_members(to_remove)
File "c:\manim-master\manimlib\utils\family_ops.py", line 5, in extract_mobject_family_members result = list(it.chain(*[
File "c:\manim-master\manimlib\utils\family_ops.py", line 6, in <listcomp>mob.get_family()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_family'
```

I don't know what I need to change, someone please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to use Manim's [get_area](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.coordinate_systems.CoordinateSystem.html#manim.mobject.coordinate_systems.CoordinateSystem.get_area) method.

> **get_area**(graph, x_range=None, color=['#58C4DD', '#83C167'], opacity=0.3, bounded_graph=None, **kwargs)
>
> Returns a Polygon representing the area under the graph passed.

```
from manim import *
import numpy as np

class GraphExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        ax = Axes((-3, 10), (-1, 8))
        
        ax.add_coordinates()

        curve = ax.get_graph(lambda x: 2 * np.sin(x))

        self.add(ax, curve)

        area = ax.get_area(graph=curve, x_range=(0,2))

        self.add(area)
        self.wait(1)
```

Output:

[image: GraphExample output]